# Context path changed while loading image in html page

Tags: html, css, image, web-applications, image-loading

I am maintaining already developed web application (in Java(struts,hibernate)). 
I am getting following error in my Google-chrome console while loading one page.

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://local.myproject.co.in/this/is/just/temp/path/111' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.myproject.co.in/this/is/image/path/DEL.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.`

Here is my html code snap-shot.

```
<div id="div_1">
<img src="/this/is/image/path/DEL.png">
</div>
```

From where is it taking `http://www.myproject.co.in` instead of `https://local.myproject.co.in` in image loading path? Any idea?

Comment: Without the code we can only guess...

Comment: Hi thanks for quick reply. I also need to do some guesses as code of html page is very large, but I don't think html page code will matter in this case.